# Add a warning about snippets being dangerous when they are run

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

**WARNING: Do not run the code samples below. They are potentially destructive, and can crash a computer/server.**

Stack Snippets is not entirely secure. Some server-crashing scripts can still run:

```javascript
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/");
for (i=1;i>0;i++) {
  xhr.send();
}
```

This sends infinite requests and can (instantly) crash a server. Another example is the client-side bomb:

```javascript
for (i=1;i>0;i++) {
  var a = "This is dangerous!";
}
```

This, unfortunately, can also crash a browser.

So can Stack Snippets be confirmation-to-run when they have dangerous items (e.g. infinite loops, cookies, or infinite server requests)?

Comment: Re *"can also crash a browser"*: What browser, incl. the version, did you try it on?

Comment: Any modern web browser will not allow a single loop 100% of its CPU time to prevent crashes, and warn the user/terminate the code if it's unresponsive for a longer period. This really should not be an issue, unless you're using a very old JS engine. If this were a real issue, visiting a malicious web page would cause a crash too, and that hasn't been the case the last decade.

Comment: Before the server crashes your IP is black listed by the HA-Proxy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> So can Stack Snippets be confirmation-to-run when they have dangerous items (e.g. infinite loops, cookies, or infinite server requests)?

This is provably impossible. It would require solving the halting problem, which is [described by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) as:

> In computability theory, the halting problem is the problem of determining, from a description of an arbitrary computer program and an input, whether the program will finish running, or continue to run forever. Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist.

Note that bit at the end stating that a general algorithm to solve the problem cannot exist.  Unfortunately, determining whether a program runs forever (i.e., an infinite loop) or performs some other particular action is thus impossible.  Imagine, for instance, a piece of code that checks if the user is a normal user or the detection system before running the infinite loop.  Or perhaps it queries a remote server to ask whether to do it.  If this were possible to detect, writing anti-malware software would be a lot easier.

---

Separately, it's worth noting that running the client-side one in the Stack Snippet editor *doesn't* crash my browser (Firefox), just freezes the page for a little while until I get asked by the browser if I want to stop it.

Comment: For updated versions of chrome, nothing crashes for me. In fact my chrome just reloads the page. So it's not too much of a problem.

Comment: Not impossible if you assume all snippets are potentially dangerous.